# Syntax to filter NSArray of arrays by key

Tags: ios, arrays, key-value

I am looking for a one-liner if possible to get the value for a key for an array of arrays.

If the array looks like:

```
NSArray *images = @[@[@"blue",@"blue.png"],[@"red",@"red.png"]];
```

I am looking for something that will return `[@"red",@"red.png"]` if you give it red as an argument.

I feel like there should be something like

```
NSArray *match = [images ValueForKey:@"red"];
```

however that gives error `'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key'`

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: You would be better off creating an array of dictionaries or structures or an array of objects rather than an array of arrays

Comment: There are lot of pre-existing arrays and they are used in other code.  I could convert them to dictionaries prior to the search.  Alternatively, is there a way to reference the dimension of a multidimensional array?  myArray[0] gives you the object reference but is there syntax to reference a certain dimension ie myArray[0][0]?

Comment: You will need to loop over the outer array and examine the first element of each inner array. There isn’t really a “one liner” but the amount of “work” that the CPU does is the same whether you write the loop or it is “hidden” behind a function